# Как модифицировать паттерн SIngleton?

Tags: c#, шаблоны-проектирования

Была задача сделать парсер данных из вебсокета. Для этого я использовал паттерг `Singleton`. Когда одна пара валют - все работает отлично. Однако, допустим у меня n таких валют? Я хочу чтобы переменные у каждого `Singleton` были свои. Звучит нелепо конечно, но может я не тот паттерн юзаю?

```
public class Singleton
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<Singleton> lazy =
            new Lazy<Singleton>(() => new Singleton());

        public string Name { get; private set; }
        public List<string> List = new List<string>();
        public void Run(string pair)
        {


//Тут получаем данные этой пары и результат пихаем в список List
......
         List.Add(Name);
        }
        private Singleton()
        {
            Name = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        public static Singleton GetInstance()
        {
            return lazy.Value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: По каким критериям вы выбрали такой паттерн? Он же зовется на русском Одиночка. Значит может быть только один. А вам похоже нужно как раз несколько...

Comment: @Bulson а какой юзать?

Comment: `Я хочу чтобы переменные у каждого Singleton были свои` вы где то свернули не туда. Чтобы понять где, надо знать, что вы делаете и зачем и в чем вообще ваша задача.

Comment: Создайте обычный класс и не морочьте себе голову.

Comment: @Radzhab я бы на этом уровне знания программирования советовал бы ПОЛНОСТЬЮ ЗАБЫТЬ все паттерны программирования которые ты знаешь. Это частая ошибка начинающих пихать паттерн куда не попадя просто потому что есть знания о нем. Забудь и просто программируй. Без всяких паттернов.